# Samsung Keyboard of keybinding of switching input methods

Tags: samsung, external-keyboard

How do I disable the 'Shift + Space' keybinding of Samsung Keyboard, which triggers the toggling of input methods? I use a physical keyboard, and it is quite easy (and annoying) for my system to misinterprete my ' Capital letter followed by a space' into switching the input methods.

Also I don't want to root my device.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Microsoft Wedge keyboard and what solved it for me was installing SwiftKey or some other keyboard alternative and setting that as the default instead of the Samsung one.

This is a fantastically annoying default shortcut that's impossible to turn off and easily identifiable to anyone using an external keyboard and writing in English, every single time I would write "I", it would eat the space after it and change language instead... The problem probably exists for all physical keyboards as with the on-screen keyboard the shortcut still exists, but most people are not fast enough to trigger it there.